# Display tkMessageBox above all other running applications

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a python program that, at a certain point when conditions are met, displays a tkMessageBox.

The intended use of this program is to start it, minimize it and then after a certain time get the alert. But when I use tkMessageBox, the message stays 'hidden' behind all the other applications that I have opened (Firefox etc.).

Is there a way to put the messagebox in focus/push it above all the other applications?

Thank you.

Edit: I'm using Lubuntu and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make tkMessageBox raise above all other windows only along side with root:

```
from Tkinter import Tk              # For this example we only need Tk
from tkMessageBox import showinfo

root = Tk()         # We need a main window

def showMessage():
    root.attributes('-topmost', 1)              # Raising root above all other windows
    root.attributes('-topmost', 0)              
    showinfo("Title", "Sample text Message")    # Actual message

root.after(3000, showMessage)       # Starting function 'showMessage' in 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds)
root.mainloop()                     # Starting mainloop
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It started working by itself, no idea why :D Hopefully your post can help someone in the future (haven't tried it).